# Apache showing default testing site instead of index.php it is directed to show

Tags: php, apache, centos

LTR, FTP

```
cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)

httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Nov  5 2018 01:47:09

php -v
PHP 7.2.16 (cli) (built: Mar  5 2019 14:45:10) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.16, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

Okay, with some pertinent info out of the way, on to the explanation of the problem.

I've got two domains, running from the same web server.
Domain 1 (callmeloopdaddy.com) is working perfectly. I am using h5ai to show a nice view of file on the subdomain archive.callmeloopdaddy.com.
Now I have Domain 2: daviddaily.dev. I would like to be doing the same thing as archive.cmld.com on ahk.daviddaily.dev, but it is not behaving.

I'm trying to set up the same thing on both, but apache always shows the testing page instead of what I tell it to show when I go to ahk.daviddaily.dev.
https://ahk.daviddaily.dev/ should eventually look exactly the same as https://archive.callmeloopdaddy.com/.ahk/
Here's the Virtual Hosts settings, which (as far as I can see) are identical.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName archive.callmeloopdaddy.com
    ServerAlias www.archive.callmeloopdaddy.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/archive/
        DirectoryIndex  /_h5ai/public/index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =archive.callmeloopdaddy.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.archive.callmeloopdaddy.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

and

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ahk.daviddaily.dev
    ServerAlias www.ahk.daviddaily.dev

    DocumentRoot /var/www/ddaily/ahk
        DirectoryIndex /_h5ai/public/index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =ahk.daviddaily.dev [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.ahk.daviddaily.dev
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

I `cp`'ed the _h5ai folder from /var/www/archive/ to /var/www/ddaily/ahk, so the structure in there is 100% the same.

Any help would be appreciated, please show me your ways.

Also no, I'm not switching to nginx, I tried that and I can't get PHP to work no matter what guide I follow.

Comment: From what I see your HTTP VHost works fine, it redirects to `https://ahk.daviddaily.dev/`. Can you post your HTTPS (:443) VHost?

Comment: Huh, I just now realized that I don't think I have one set up for a single site. Must be something I fucked up with `certbot`

Answer (score 0):

I had not checked to see what the HTTPS VHost was set to. This was automagically created by Certbot and hand;t been updated to match the correct directory tree. Now that I've fixed that, it all works very well.